# What property will fetch me the Wikipedia description of a topic?

Tags: freebase, mql

I know of the /common/topic/description property of a topic. When I visit a particular topic's page, there are many instances of this property for a topic. Which of these are the description from wikipedia (if exists for a topic) ?

The basic objective is to get a description for a topic, and to give top priority to the Wikipedia description if exists for a topic.

What property of a topic will help me fetch this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you request the `/common/topic/description` from the [Topic API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview) you'll see citation data which tell's you that a description came from Wikipedia.

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic//m/09c7w0?filter=/common/topic/description

```
{
 "id": "/m/09c7w0",
 "property": {
  "/common/topic/description": {
   "valuetype": "string",
   "values": [
    {
     "text": "The United States of America, commonly called the United States and America, is a federal...",
     "lang": "en",
     "creator": "/user/wikirecon_bot",
     "project": "wikirecon",
     "dataset": "/m/0kj4zz_",
     "citation": {
      "provider": "Wikipedia",
      ...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thanks Shawn! So does that mean the /common/topic/description could come not just from Wikipedia but also from other sources (such as users themselves adding their descriptions)? so I was wondering about the multiple instances of this property for a question and now I got the answer :) Thanks!